# How do i stop my form from resizing on a mobile device?

Tags: php, css, forms, mobile, responsive

i have a completed site in PHP i am now placing the viewport coding to make it mobile friendly, so far so good. A problem that i have run into is when people click on my form on their phones the phone increases the size of the form to help them see the fields better as most phone browsers but once they have filled in the form it leaves the form oversized and the user has to decrease the size of the form manually. How can i stop the phones brower (IE Chrome and Safari) from increase the size of my form page ? I have tried using max-width and max-height in CSS but no luck. Any advice ?

Comment: Please share your code so we can help debug it.

Comment: People expect to see what you tried (your code), in a well formatted question. Help them help you. Please take the [**stack overflow tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know more about this site, and read about **[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. You may also read **[how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**, especially the bit about answering well asked questions.

Comment: sure thing..   Sorry im new to stack how do i past my code ? it doesnt fit into the character limit in the comments section.

Comment: @Nunes you can use Bootstrap it easy to use and responsive!

Comment: @Nunes : you can edit the question.